# Date formatting from a derived/computed column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column(A) in excel with data like "20141024X000000". First part before x is a date.
In another column(B) I want to format the date to become like "14-Oct-24"

What I did was use this function on column B to get the date part and add "/" to separate it to make it look like this "2014/10/24":

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,4),"/",MID(A1,5,2),"/",MID(A1,7,2)))
```

I tried using the cell formatter on the column and the cell to convert it to the desired date format but somehow does not work.

I know I can use vlookup with a reference for number and month starts to format it the way i like however I don't want to use a reference.

Is there some other way to make this work or do this without using reference for the months?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your `IF` statement is backwards. It's telling Excel `IF A1 is blank, run the formula, otherwise do nothing`. Basically, its a "do nothing" formula. Was that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula + date formatting worked out for me. You can encapsulate it in your IF statement.

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,2)&"/"&MID(A1,7,2)&"/"&LEFT(A1,4))
```

[image]